# move one specific object prop from one array to another array of objects, if condition (JavaScript ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays of objects returning from 2 different fetch

```
const result1 = [
  {
    name: 'matteo',
    age: 20,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'luca',
    age: 24,
    id: 2,
  },
];

const result2 = [
  {
    warnings: 'yes',
    hobby: "tennis",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    warnings: 'many',
    hobby: "ping pong",
    id: 2,
  },
];
```

This is my current approach but it will merge the entire object from result2 to result1 if they have the same id

```
const t = result2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.id] = curr;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const d = result1.map((d) =>
    Object.assign(d, t[d.id]) 
  );
```

The current result is:

```
{
    name: 'matteo',
    age: 20,
    id: 1,
warnings: "yes",
hobby: "tennis"
  },
  {
    name: 'luca',
    age: 24,
    id: 2,
warnings: "many",
hobby: "ping pong"
  },
```

I would like to move only the warnings prop from the second array of objects into the first array of objects where the id of object is equal

Desired output:

```
const result3 = [
      {
        name: 'matteo',
        age: 20,
        id: 1,
        warnings: "yes"
      },
      {
        name: 'luca',
        age: 24,
        id: 2,
        warnings: "many"
      },
    ];
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: so far I was able to merge all properties from the second array to the first one but since the the objects contain a lot of properties I would like to move only the warnings one.
This what I did so far:
const t = result2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.id] = curr;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const d = result1.map((d) =>
    Object.assign(d, t[d.id]) 
  );

Comment: So give a [mre] that shows exactly where the problem is.

Comment: const t = result2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.id] = curr;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const d = result1.map((d) =>
    Object.assign(d, t[d.id]) 
  );

Comment: [Edit] the question. Show the outputs of that and how they differ from what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to create a new array, and `find` to get any warning with a matching id:

```js
let result1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a', age: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'b', age: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'c', age: 3 },
  { id: 4, name: 'd', age: 4 }
];

let result2 = [
  { id: 1, hobby: 'aa', warnings: 'aaa' },
  { id: 2, hobby: 'bb', warnings: 'bbb' },
  { id: 4, hobby: 'dd', warnings: 'ddd' }
];

let includeWarnings = (data, warningsArr) => data.map(obj => {
  
  // `w` will be undefined if no matching warning is found
  let w = warningsArr.find(warn => warn.id === obj.id);
  
  // Return all the data in `obj`, and the "warnings" property
  // of `w` if `w` is defined
  return { ...obj, ...(w ? { warnings: w.warnings } : {}) };
  
});
console.log(includeWarnings(result1, result2));
```

Note you'd potentially be better off if your data format was structured with `id` mappings in mind:

```
let result1 = {
  id1: { name: 'name1', age: 1 },
  id2: { name: 'name2', age: 2 },
  .
  .
  .
}

let result2 = {
  id1: { hobby: 'hobby1', warnings: 'warnings1' },
  id2: { hobby: 'hobby2', warnings: 'warnings2' },
  .
  .
  .
}
```